# What is a good development setup for Ionicframework

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-native

I’m using Ionic with Angular to write an iOS and Android app.
But most of the development I use `ionic serve` with Chrome, it’s fast and simple.

But now I realized that it’s getting harder when I have to use the native HTTP API to do fundamental things like talking to a rest api on my server. The native HTTP api is working for the iOS/Android app in production, but not in the web app mode I’m using for development.

I know that I there are options like live reload for iOS and Android but they are still lazy in my point of view.

So I’m asking you:
**Do you prefer developing directly with iOS/Android emulator/devices or are you also using the web app and found a way around the troubles above?**

Comment: Opinion-based
This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way you can test native HTTP on the browser. you have to use an emulator or a native device. BUT, for testing UI you can run the command `ionic serve --lab` instead of `ionic serve`. do it and see the difference.

to test HTTP on the browser you must use HttpClient.